# Why my kotlin code for Firebase authentication not working?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I am enrolled in online CBT and learning Kotlin for android programming. The video tutes were made in 2017 and I got codes of the apps that were made in the to the tutorial series. I have followed every step till I connect my app with Firebase and even entered sample user data in  Authentication and set Usage Rules to public, but to my surprise same Kotlin code which was shown to be working flawlessly in video tutorials does not work for me.
Then I tried sample LoginActivity.kt and RegisterActivity.kt codes from github, even those codes does not work. Please look at my codes and help me sort out this issue.
When I click on loginBtn the app crashes and not data is sent to Firebase. Logcat shows following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.paramlowe.mypg2. Make sure to call 
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(SourceFile:218)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getInstance(Unknown Source:1)
    at com.punjabweb.myapp.LoginActivity.loginUser(LoginActivity.kt:50)
    at 
com.punjabweb.myapp.LoginActivity.access$loginUser(LoginActivity.kt:25)
    at
```

com.punjabweb.myapp.LoginActivity$onCreate$2.onClick(LoginActivity.kt:43)

and my kotlin code for LoginActivity.kt is here below:

```
package com.punjabweb.myapp2

import android.content.Intent
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.text.TextUtils
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Toast
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_login.*

class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    //Firebase references
    private var mAuth: FirebaseAuth? = null
//    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)

        val loginBtn = findViewById<View>(R.id.btnLogin) as Button



        loginBtn.setOnClickListener {
            loginUser()
        }

    } 


    private fun loginUser() {
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        val email = etEmail?.text.toString()
        val password = etPassword?.text.toString()
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email) && TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
             Toast.makeText(this, "Enter all details", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        } else {
             mAuth!!.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                 .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
     if (task.isSuccessful) {  
 // Sign in success, update UI with signed-in user's information
     var firebasUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!

                        //      updateUI()
                    } else {
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. 
                           Toast.makeText(
                            this@LoginActivity, "Authentication failed.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        ).show()
                    }
                }
        }

        fun updateUI() {
            val intent = Intent(this@LoginActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
//            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
        startActivity(intent)
        }
}
 }
```

Comment: Is `FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this)` normally commented out in your code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the firebase email authentication in the console. Seems like your code is ok in the first look.
This could potentially be cause because you don't have the google-services plugin at the end of app gradle:

```
dependencies {
    ....
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Thanks @Bhargav Rao for help but this does not resolve the issue. There seems to some issue with button itself. When I click on login button even without entering any data in form the app crashes and does not prompt to fill entries first. In java we need to instantiate buttons with findViewByID but in Kotlin it is not required so I have tried even direct code btnLogin.setOnClickListener but the app keeps on crashing.

Comment: considering the amount of days going waste in resolving tiny issues in Kotlin, I am now switching back to java based android development. For me Kotlin hasn't worked well. I think google should first set a standard code for kotlin programming.

Comment: I just want to say this for the record if anyone else browses this post. This issue has NOTHING to do with Kotlin or Java. It's likely a issue with the OP's implementation of the Firebase.